# xcrun error: Failed to read entitlements from 

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcodebuild

So im trying to automate the build and archive process through a script.  In my script, I run the xcodebuild script and that builds fine.  Then I try to run the xcrun

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "path_to_.app" -o "output_path" --sign "devname" --embed "provnprofile"
```

However I get this error:

```
error: Failed to read entitlements from '/var/folders/U5/U5q0xqZRG6SrO8AMQkMjeE+++TM/-Tmp-/fIcrdMUa76/Payload/MyApp.app'
```

Anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue. It was actually related to my .app folder generated with xcodebuild which wasn't successfully built.

Try to use xcodebuild with the verbose (-verbose) enabled and check the stack trace.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Looks like the correct flag is `-verbose` not `-v` (for both `xcodebuild` and `xcrun`.)

Answer (score 0):

double check the package you are building in Xcode. Very often, a project has multiple packages and targets to build. You might have selected a distribution package or not the one you intent to build.